Problem with exaggerated displacement or normals in my texture
I have three materials that I did in substance designer and imported to one project in blender.

The hight and normal maps are in Open Gl, so it's not a problem with DirectX texutres.
There is probably a problem with displacement map.
The problem is not happening in some meshes, instead of exagerated displacement map, it looks like it don't have any (image below)


Also, here is the shader configuration of the material (image below)

Plese, if you have any hint about this problem or need more informations to understand, let me know!
Thank you!

Hello, if Daniel's answer doesn't answer, please pack your images and share your file (only the 2 objects you show)

Hints:

Different meshes have different UV maps, so the scale of the textures may be different in each mesh, check the UV maps, see how they fit the texture image. Make sure both meshes have similar UV scales

Different meshes may have different face sizes. Displacement (if material "settings" are set to "displacement") need the geometry to have enough subdivisions, otherwise ugly artifacts appear. Make sure the meshes have a similar (and enough) number of faces

You can increase decrease the normals strenght and the scale of the displacement.

Look at both meshes from several different angles and move the light also in several different angles, somethings will be only visible from certain angles


